# How to unpin gdb for uninstall?

Tags: macos, gdb

I tried `$ brew uninstall gdb` and `$ brew rm gdb`, but it didn't work for me, because I need to unpin it at first. My error message:

```
Error: gdb is pinned. You must unpin it to uninstall.
```

How can I unpin the gdb?

Comment: I guess this have nothing to do with gdb use, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

To unpin gdb, you should run:

```
brew unpin gdb
```